# Extract filename from text file using regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Folks,

I am not an expert in regular expressions and I've searched Google for my problem but haven't found a solution. If anybody finds another SO post with same question, please feel free to point to that post.

**Question:**

I got a text file with much of the characters as html tags. These text files may contain PDF filename as shown below. I just want to extract all such PDF filenames with `.pdf` extension. Note that these PDF filenames may come anywhere in the text document string, not only after `<FILENAME>` prefix.

**Example Text:**

```
Example 1: <FILENAME>any_valid_characters_filename.pdf
Example 2: hello this is a good file abc-def_xyz-1.pdf
```

Note here `<FILENAME>` is a valid (html) tag in my text document. I want to extract the filename `any_valid_characters_filename.pdf` and `abc-def_xyz-1.pdf`. These valid characters for PDF filename could be `a-Z`, `A-Z`, `_`, `-`, `.`, `0-9` but not special characters like `<`, `>` etc.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
r'\b(\w+\.pdf)\b'
r'^\\(.+\\)*(.+)\.(.+)\.pdf$'
r'[^A-Za-z0-9_\.pdf]' 
r'[\\/:"*?<>|]+\.pdf'
```

and bunch of other regex expressions but did not have success.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If the filenames cannot contain whitespaces, you may use something like `r'>([^\s\\/:"*?<>|]+\.pdf)\b'`

Comment: Let's assume filenames may contain whitespaces (although unlikely). Does this still work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Using your regex, it throws me Syntax error at ? character.

Comment: Remove `\s` from the pattern. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mplq8a/2). There is no error in my pattern, but in your code, I do not see what code you have, please add it to the question.

Comment: Using `re.findall(r">([^\\/:"*?<>|]+\.pdf)\b", "<FILENAME>abc-1def.pdf")` throws the syntax error.

Comment: Well, you need other string literal delimiters, use single quotes. See https://ideone.com/58AhzX, `r'>([^\\/:"*?<>|]+\.pdf)\b'`. You pasted my string literal into your code where you had `"` as string literal delimiters. Or better use `r"""pattern_here"""`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, this worked for sample text as shown above. Wondering if this would work for detecting PDF filenames anywhere (with or without any prefix/suffix). Thank you BTW!

Comment: There is no 100% safe regex matching a file name. You should tell us what contexts your expected matches occur in, then we can help. Otherwise, it is an unclear question. You say there is `>` on the left. What is on the right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Apart from the text example above, another example where I have to find a filename is something like this: `hello this is a good file abc-def_xyz-1.pdf`. Something along this line.

Comment: Also, added the new example to my question. Thank you.

Comment: From my experience, I know that if the file name can have whitespace, it is too hard to write a safe regex to extract it from anywhere in the text. I'd use something like `[^\s<>]+\.pdf` and add any other non-allowed chars to the pattern to adjust it for the concrete case. It will extract those file names that have no whitespace, but I'd get rid of much rubbish that I would get with a pattern that allows whitespace

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I understand your point of difficulty regarding whitespaces in filename. It is difficult. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Perhaps a 2 stage fitering might be in order, first use (\S*\.pdf) to collect strings that end in pdf, and then handle the array of matches.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following expression covers everything you mentioned:

```
r"([\w\d\-.]+\.pdf)"
```

As it matches any composition with a word character, a digit character, a `-` symbol and a `.` symbol followed by `.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks. If I just want to use the first example case, (and ignore the second example match), what changes do I need? Note I want to ignore all whitespaces between the strings "<FILENAME>" and ".pdf" in the example 1. If there are whitespaces between the strings "<FILENAME>" and ".pdf" I want to ignore this match

Comment: Try `r"<FILENAME>\s*([\w\d\-.]+\.pdf)"`, it will match `<FILENAME>` followed by a valid pdf name.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But this doesn't work when there is a space after `>` and before start of any word or filename. Check here https://ideone.com/xPQTYI

Answer (score 1):

Can this work?

```
\b[^\s<>]*?.pdf\b
```

It works for your examples: https://regexr.com/43b8q

Update for your new request that no space exist between `<FILENAME>` and `whatever.pdf`:

Use: `\b(?<![<>][\s]|\w)[\w-]*?.pdf\b`

example: https://regex101.com/r/O3kpQ4/2/

Comment: Thanks. If I just want to use the first example case, (and ignore the second example match), what changes do I need? Note I want to ignore all whitespaces between the strings "<FILENAME>" and ".pdf" in the example 1. If there are whitespaces between the strings "<FILENAME>" and ".pdf" I want to ignore this match

Comment: Try this? `\b(?<![<>][\s]|\w)[\w-]*?.pdf\b`

Comment: Thanks. But I want to ignore Example 2 because it doesn't have prefix of `<FILENAME>` in your updated shared link

Comment: All of this should go into your question description. Now the regex string will be completely different - and people can't help you if you keep moving the goal post. Here `\b(?<=<.*>)[\w-]*?.pdf\b`